# Как отправить гиперссылку от менеджера в чат бота Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Есть бот сервисной поддержки. Нужно, чтобы менеджер мог отправить пользователю сообщение с гепрессылкой. Сообщения от пользователя просто форвардятся в чат поддержки, а вот в сообщении от менеджера пока просто копируется текст и отправляется пользователю. Как копировать текст вместе с гиперссылкой?

```
   # Обработчик всех сообщений от менеджера
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: str(message.chat.id) == SUPPORT_CHAT_ID and message.reply_to_message is not None, content_types=["text", "photo", "document", "audio", "video", "voice", "sticker", "video_note", "location"])
def handle_support_message(message):
    user_chat_id = message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id if message.reply_to_message.forward_from else None

    # Проверяем, находится ли пользователь в режиме оператора
    if operator_mode.get(user_chat_id, False):
        if message.content_type == "text":
            bot.send_message(user_chat_id, message.text)
        elif message.content_type == "photo":
            bot.send_photo(user_chat_id, message.photo[-1].file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "video":
            bot.send_video(user_chat_id, message.video.file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "sticker":
            bot.send_sticker(user_chat_id, message.sticker.file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "audio":
            bot.send_audio(user_chat_id, message.audio.file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "document":
            bot.send_document(user_chat_id, message.document.file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "voice":
            bot.send_voice(user_chat_id, message.voice.file_id)
        elif message.content_type == "location":
            # Пересылаем локацию от менеджера
            bot.forward_message(user_chat_id, SUPPORT_CHAT_ID, message.message_id)


# Обработчик всех сообщений от пользователей в режиме оператора
@bot.message_handler (func=lambda message: str(message.chat.id) != SUPPORT_CHAT_ID and operator_mode.get(message.chat.id, False),
                      content_types=["text", "photo", "document", "audio", "video", "voice", "sticker", "video_note","location"])
def handle_message(message):
    bot.forward_message(SUPPORT_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    if not flag.get(message.chat.id, False):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мне нужно время, чтобы всё посчитать и предложить тебе наилучшие условия")
        flag[message.chat.id] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все проще. Теперь и пользователь и оператор могут обмениваться любыми сообщениями. А мне, на будущее больше, надо больше курить API

```
# Обработчик всех сообщений от менеджера
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: str(message.chat.id) == SUPPORT_CHAT_ID and message.reply_to_message is not None,
                 content_types=["text", "photo", "document", "audio", "video", "voice", "sticker", "video_note", "location"])
def handle_support_message(message):
    user_chat_id = message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id if message.reply_to_message.forward_from else None
    bot.copy_message(chat_id = user_chat_id ,from_chat_id = SUPPORT_CHAT_ID, message_id=message.message_id)


# Обработчик всех сообщений от пользователей в режиме оператора
@bot.message_handler (func=lambda message: str(message.chat.id) != SUPPORT_CHAT_ID and operator_mode.get(message.chat.id, False),
                 content_types=["text", "photo", "document", "audio", "video", "voice", "sticker", "video_note", "location"])
def handle_message(message):
    bot.forward_message(SUPPORT_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```